# Shiny Webapp - Call a separate R script and return those results

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, shiny

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

Build a shiny webapp where users can do the following:
1) input data into text fields,
2) click a submit button,
3) the submit runs a separate R script
4) the R script runs a POST call a retrieves the resulting JSON
5) the R script returns the results to the shiny web app
6) the web app displays the results

**Here's my question:**
**How do I call the separate R script from my shiny web-app?**
**How do I return the results to my shiny web-app?**

A little bit more detail...I'm working on a school project and we are trying to figure out how to integrate Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio with R. It's pretty exciting. I've created an end point for Azure Machine Learning Studio to receive input so it can run a prediction algorithm, I'm trying to connect with that.

I'm pretty new to building Shiny web apps though. Here's my current code:

app.r

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("term", 
                  label = "Term Length", 
                  choices = list("36 months" = "36 months", "60 months" = "60 months"), 
                  selected = 1),
        textInput("my_text", 
                  label = "Text input",
                  value = "Enter text..."),
        numericInput("my_num",
                  label = "Numeric input", 
                  value = 1),
        submitButton(text="Submit"),
        actionButton("do", "Click Me")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("text1")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



   output$text1 <- renderText({
     paste("You have selected ", input$term)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

R script for POST call to machine learning studio:

```
library("RCurl")
library("rjson")

# Accept SSL certificates issued by public Certificate Authorities
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

h = basicTextGatherer()
hdr = basicHeaderGatherer()

req =  list(
  Inputs = list(
    "input1"= list(
      list(
        'id' = "1",
        'member_id' = "1",
         ## other variables go here

      )
    )
  ),
  GlobalParameters = setNames(fromJSON('{}'), character(0))
)

body = enc2utf8(toJSON(req))
api_key = "my_personal_key" # Replace this with the API key for the web service
authz_hdr = paste('Bearer', api_key, sep=' ')

h$reset()
curlPerform(url = "my_url",
            httpheader=c('Content-Type' = "application/json", 'Authorization' = authz_hdr),
            postfields=body,
            writefunction = h$update,
            headerfunction = hdr$update,
            verbose = TRUE
)

headers = hdr$value()
httpStatus = headers["status"]
if (httpStatus >= 400)
{
  print(paste("The request failed with status code:", httpStatus, sep=" "))

  # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
  print(headers)
}

print("Result:")
result = h$value()
print(fromJSON(result))
```

Comment: PS: I'm assuming it has something to do with the reactive constructs like 'observe', 'observe-event', 'reactive'......something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, if anyone is curious. Quite an elementary question, but it was new to me.

I didn't need the separate R script. Instead, I copied that code and pasted it in an "ObserveEvent()" in the server-side code. The "ObserveEvent()" watches for a button to be clicked, and then I take the inputs from the user and send them in the API POST call to Azure machine learning studio. Then, within "ObserveEvent()", I call "renderText()" to get the result and save it to an output variable that is then passed to the UI.

I didn't post code because there doesn't seem to be tons of interest in this question. Request code if you'd like.

Comment: Can you post the code. I'm working on a similar thing which requires user output to be consumed by a machine learning pipeline, and then again output the results using a shiny app.